# Trying to access the Magento SOAP API on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, magento, soap

I am trying to access a `Magento SOAP API` (v 1.9.2.4) using `npm magento`. But `data` is always `null`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MagentoAPI = require('magento');
var magento = new MagentoAPI({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: '/magento/api/xmlrpc/',
  login: 'mothership',
  pass: 'bvZ0k0B02pTjujN'
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Customers: ');
});

var magentoCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('Got data: ' + data);
  console.log(data);
};

magento.login(function(err, sessId) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error accessing Magento");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Session ID: " + sessId);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Connected to Magento");
  magento.core.info(magentoCallback);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Racing on port 3000');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

today, i was the same problem and after two hours i found the resolution. You need change the magentoCallback function to :

```
var magentoCallback = function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("Result: ");
    console.log(response)
};
```